# The view is not loading due to {{ }} in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, view, summernote

I have setup *summer-note.js* on my textarea in my Laravel view, if I input any data and include `{{}}` this in the data and hit save button, the post saves successfully, but when I go to the **show route** the page is not loading at all after that I inspected it the body element was only showing, but when I viewed page source all code was displaying there, then I added a new data without `{{}}`, then I went to the **show route**, the page was loading fine, but when I include `{{}}` in the data, page doesn't load anymore, my Laravel view code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>Question # {{ $question->id }}:</h1>
    <p>{!! $question->question !!}</p>
</div>
```

I think it is due to double `{{ {{ }} }}` because when it renders data it becomes **{{ This is {{question}} #1 }}** so is there any fix of it?

I tried both `{!! $question->question !!}` and `{{ $question->question }}` but page was not loading.

Comment: Have you checked if there is anything in your error logs?

Comment: You can't use `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}` in a `.js` file; that is `.blade.php` syntax. Or, if this is a `.php` file, make sure it has `.blade` as well, so `file.blade.php` instead of `file.php`

Comment: no bro i have seen there's no error in there

Comment: @TimLewis no it's .blade.php file I have just mentioned that I was saved the data through summernote.js

Comment: if you do `gettype($question->question) what do you get?` What does $question->question contain? Is it a simple string?

Comment: string coming in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use jquery's **replaceWith()** function and put a restriction in there to convert the **{{ }}** to a HTML entity whenever it's found in the input.

HTML entity for **{** is `&#123;` and for **}** is `&#125;`

> For more information, visit [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function and for HTML entities visit [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you are probably missing the '@'

Like so:

```
@{{ '{{ test }}' }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

I did not see any issues displaying the page given the test data:

```
@php
      $test = '<p>{{Lo<u>rem ipsum dolor s<b>it amet, consectetur }}</p>';
@endphp
<p>{!! $test !!}</p>
<p>{{ $test  }}</p>
```

Also I would strongly advice against outputting unescaped html. There is probably data you have that is messing up the closing/opening tags in your templates.

[image]

Comment: Bro I have added `@{{ '{{$question->question}}' }}` but again nothing working

Comment: and if I use `@{!! $question->question !!}` it is displaying **{!! $question->question !!}** as it is

Comment: what is your data? what is the value of `$question->question` in your db?

Comment: yeah bro `$question->question` is data in my db

Comment: yes, but what is the value of this? like give an actual value.

Comment: **<p>{{Lo<u>rem ipsum dolor s<b>it amet, consectetur }}</p>** it is my data which I have saved in from textarea

Comment: sorry, i did not see any issue with your sample value. It displays fine. Maybe there some setting you have that I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try after clearing view cache

`php artisan view:clear`
And to convert your text to html use `{!! !!}`

Hope it will be helpful :)